# How To Make Full Page Background Image Without Resizing Or Cropping

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I need is what the following site does exactly but it's not a slideshow it's just a fading background image :

http://www.stevenharrisarchitects.com/

The image is 100% in width and 100% in height so no Cropping occurs, and this is what I want exactly.I had managed to do this part very easily with the following codes :

```
#bg-stat {
background: url('images/LANDING_PAGE.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
height: 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/LANDING_PAGE.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/LANDING_PAGE.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

I made the background-size : 100% 100% ;

It works fine, but the only problem that's left is that my client doesn't want the image to resize with the size of the window, instead it should act like on the site I mentioned above (Try resizing the window and you will see what I mean).

I don't want my background image to re-size to the 100% of width and height of my window, I want it to act just like in the above link I shared.

Also a link to my site :

http://leydenlewis.com/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: the links are same, and did your tried `position:fixed` ?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work as well, I need my site to have the background image in full size but when the page is resized it shouldn't be in size.like in the first link I shared.And btw, I added a link to my site.Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Have you tried background-size: 100%; ? the docs says that, if you only specify the width, the height is auto. On the example site the image resizes keeping the aspect ratio so auto is fine.

Comment: updated my answer with backround css property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use the background property and never want the image to be cropped, you should use `background-size :contain;`

```
div.big_background{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/g/1200/800') no-repeat center top;
    background-size :contain;
}
```

Comment: My site is actually using the background property, I'm getting the background image in CSS so that the logo can appear as well.

Comment: you can use the property z-index to make your logo apear over the big image.

Comment: Wow it worked well! But the only thing is that not the whole image is showing now, the rest piece of the bottom is cropped, you can see here.. http://leydenlewis.com

Comment: on the example you showed, the image is aslo croped on the bottom if the screen isn't high enough. I'm looking for a solution with the background propety.

Comment: It actually works perfect, but the bottom of the image is still not appearing.I don't know why although I set the height to 100% http://leydenlewis.com/

Comment: on my screen, I have a white border at the bottom. It means that my screen ratio is wider than the image ratio, this is normal. Be aware that it is not possible to get an image to never be cropped, cover the whole screen and keep it's aspect ratio.

Comment: As a developer I understand what you say, and it seems strange to me as well, but this is what my client wants and also on the example site I had shown it's working and the height and width is great.

Comment: To get exacly the same as your example, use my first solution with a html image. That is what your example is using

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on problem described above:

```
#bg-stat {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('images/LANDING_PAGE.jpg') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Answer based on feedback:

CSS:

```
#bg-stat {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#bg-image {
  background: url("images/LANDING_PAGE.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
  min-width: 1140px; // Based on img dimensions or arbitrary 
  max-height: 735px; // Based on img dimensions or arbitrary
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't cover the whole page, so the width is not 100% . You can see here http://leydenlewis.com/

Comment: I just saw your other reply about the background-size: 100% auto; but now the height is cropped, so not all the image is shown.Your help is very very much appreciated! Its just that my client wants that his site is background image act just like in http://www.stevenharrisarchitects.com/ the whole image is showing but when the page is resized the image doesnot resize to the full page.It only keeps the width to be 100% but the height is not, however when you open it in a normal browser and do not resize it, the height is perfectly fitting the window size along with the width.

Comment: My first response mimics the example URL you provided. Test and see. When user expands window width, aspect ratio is challenged and part of the image height hides outside of the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need below code:

```
body
{
 background: url(image/background.jpg);
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
}
```